# Buscar dos valores con re.search

Tags: python, python-3.x

Me gustaría saber si se puede buscar en un archivo de texto, usando `re.search`, dos valores distintos en una misma variable (se que se puede obtener usando dos variables) ya que quiero "asociar" el valor1 al valor2 y trabajar conjuntamente con ellos.

archivo.txt:

```
ESTE ES UN ARCHIVO QUE CONTIENE EL VALOR120 CON LA MIDA50
```

Con un valor sería así:

```
with open(archivo.txt) as archivo:
    for linea in archivo:    
        valor= re.search(r"VALOR(\d+)", archivo)
```

Con dos valores a buscar, se me ha ocurrido esto, pero no me ha funcionado:

```
valor= re.search(r"VALOR(\d+)|MIDA(\d+)", archivo)
```

El output que me gustaría obtener es el siguiente: `120, 50`

Comment: Si ambas palabras están en la misma línea, puedes usar `r"VALOR(\d+).*MIDA(\d+)"`

Comment: Si, estàn en la misma línea. No me ha funcionado, el output de `valor` es NONE

Answer (score 0):

La expresión regular necesita un pequeño cambio, que es reemplazar el operador "|" por ".+", que significa "cualquier cosa entre VALORxxx y MIDAyyy" con al menos un caracter de separación.

Si usas ".*", también aceptaras que dichas palabras vayan pegadas, como "VALOR120MIDA130". Tienes que ver cual valida mejor tu entrada.

Queda asi:

```
import re

test = "ESTE ES UN ARCHIVO QUE CONTIENE EL VALOR120 CON LA MIDA50"
pattern = re.compile("VALOR(\d+).+MIDA(\d+)")
m = pattern.search(test)
if m:
    print("Match completo=", m[0])
    print("Primer grupo captura=", m[1])
    print("Segundo grupo de captura=", m[2])
```

produce:

```
Match completo= VALOR120 CON LA MIDA50
Primer grupo captura= 120
Segundo grupo de captura= 50
```

Comment: No es lo que indico que quiero obtener en la pregunta.

Comment: Lo escribi asi con propósitos ilustrativos. Para tu necesidad, puedes modificar el `print`. No es tan difícil ni esperaras que te lo den todo cocinado.

Comment: Si te fijas, indico que quiero obtener el valor 120 y 50, en la misma variable, sin tener que usar el índice de posición en la variable m

Comment: Tampoco es tan difícil: `variable = (m[1], m[2])`.

Comment: El metodo funciona si usas una variable, si trabajas con un archivo como he indicado en la pregunta, no.

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de `re.search()`, en tu caso yo usaría la función `findall()` del mismo módulo `re`. (Casi) Siempre que quieras obtener múltiples valores basado en un patrón, esta es la opción a elegir. Con esta función obtendrás una lista de los fragmentos de la string que solo cumplan con el patrón que indicas (en lugar de tener que hacer un patrón que haga *match* con toda la string).

También otro cambio que te sugiero hacer es usar grupos de captura y de no captura (puede leer más sobre ellos [acá](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html)) dentro de tu patrón de expresión regular.

Sería así (para cada línea de tu archivo):

```
linea = 'ESTE ES UN ARCHIVO QUE CONTIENE EL VALOR120 CON LA MIDA50'
valores = re.findall(r'(?:VALOR|MIDA)(\d+)', linea)
```

`valores` contendrá lo siguiente:

```
['120', '50']
```